# Why is my SharePoint Designer not showing my layout pages?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer

**What I want to achieve:**

I want to use a custom page layout for a site in my Site Pages Library and therefore upload a Layout Page into the SharePoint Site via SharePoint Designer 2013.

**My current status:**

My site type is a Team Site, but I have the Publishing features on the site collection and in the site settings enabled.

**What I have already tried:**

I am trying to upload a layout page with SharePoint Designer on my Page Layout folder within my site. This steps seems to work, but after the upload is "finished" the specific file is not visible in the Designer like you can see here:

[image]

Does anyone know why SharePoint Designer is not showing this file? And yes, I have restarted the Designer already.

**EDIT:**

I have found the file in `_catalogs -> masterpage`, but when I try to open my site (which is connected to the layout page), it crashes with following error screen:

[image]

**EDIT 2:**

I have also checked my Layout and Template Site Settings and found that all layouts should be usable on my site:

[image]

But still I cannot view the page with this layout page.

Comment: Did you check in All files --> Catalogs-- > masterpage section?

Comment: @Unnie yes the pages is visible in the masterpage folder and the my Site is also connected to this Layout Page but as soon as I try to open the Site it fails with an error message saying `This page is not using a valid page layout.  To correct the problem, edit page settings and select a valid page layout."`

Comment: go to site settings --> Under Look and Feel --> Page Layouts and site template settings--> check the configuration of Page Layouts. Check whether your custom  page layout  is allowed to be used.

Comment: @Unnie have adapted my question

Comment: Which content type is displayed besides your page layout name in _catalogs/masterpage section (list view)?

Comment: @Snickbrack did my answer help resolve your issue, can you please mark it as answer if it did so.

Comment: actually I have not been able to work with your explanation... (other stuff to do ;) )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SHORT ANSWER**

---

> You need to associate the file to appropriate pagelayouts content
>   types.

**EXPLANATION**

---

> When you upload a file to master pages and pagelayouts gallery it is
>   assigned to design file content type.

[image]

[image]

> If you want the pagelayout to be visible under the pagelayouts option
>   for a page, make sure to assign pagelayout content to the file being
>   uploaded to the master page and pagelayouts gallery.

[image]

[image]

> The file with properly content association will appear under
>   pagelayouts options for a page in edit mode.

[image]